# Google Cloud Platform - Deploy a Cloud Function that starts a webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, automation

I am defining a Cloud Function on GCP for **scraping** a website in Python.

I am starting simple by defining a function that simply opens the webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def launch_search(request):
    # Starting a webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return 'Success'
```

This function doesn't work (`Error: could not handle the request` when I trigger it), probably because the Chrome Driver is not installed on my remote machine. Therefore:

- How can I install it?
- Or can I **scrape** a webpage using Selenium, without opening the page with a webdriver?

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently use Python to run Selenium scripts. There's a Feature Request in the Public Issue Tracker currently open for this that can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/129757153).

As an alternative, you can use Node.JS with Puppeteer. I found [this](https://rominirani.com/using-puppeteer-in-google-cloud-functions-809a14856e14) blog post that details a use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very helpful. Do you know any other cloud service that I could use to automate my Selenium script, using Python?

Comment: From a quick search, you could give SeleniumBase a try: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/tree/master/integrations/google_cloud

Comment: You could also host it on Heroku https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ven-pqwk3ec

Answer (score 2):

Given that Cloud Functions are Serverless, you are unable to control the server machine.
You can use other manageable services such as [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/) or [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that it is possible to run selenium on Google Cloud Functions. If you're fine with a JavaScript/TypeScript example instead of Python, I recommend that you try this template: https://github.com/ccorcos/gcloud-functions-selenium-boilerplate